# How to upload .zip file into server (ubuntu OS) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.6

Good day everyone! I just want to ask on how to upload .zip file into server (in Ubuntu OS)?

Case: I want to upload .zip file in a folder in the desktop of my server computer (Ubuntu OS).

What I've done so far: I already have my UI and some codes.

Upload File Controller:

```
public function __construct() {
   view()->share('page_title', 'File Upload');
}
public function index(){
    $data = File::all();
    return view('pages.admin.system.file-upload.index',compact('data'));
}
public function create(){
    return view('pages.admin.system.file-upload.create');
}
public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
    'filename' => 'required',
    'filename.*' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip'
    ]);

    if($request->hasfile('filename')) {
        foreach($request->file('filename') as $file) {
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move(public_path().'/system/', $name, $extension);  
            $data[] = $name;  
       }
    }
    $file= new File();
    $file->filename=json_encode($data);
    $file->save();
    session()->flash('save', 'Your files has been successfully added');
    return view('pages.admin.system.file-upload.index');
}
```

What should be my next move? Do I need to configure some code in FileStorage.php? and what should be the right path in this `$file->move(public_path().'/system/', $name, $extension);`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see, first of all public_path() returns the path of the public folder in your project's root. This is because normally you shouldn't write outside that folder for security reasons. 
There are ways to override that, but I'd suggest you simply make a link on that desktop that points at that folder. You'll probably have to manage permissions, so that that particular user can access the content of the public folder (and best only that folder).

Also, the "desktop" is a folder in a user's home, and it depends on what desktop manager you're using (KDE, Gnome, etc.), so if you want to write the data in every user's desktop, you'd have to replicate the data, which is not a good idea.

So, I'd just put the files on a public folder subfolder and a symbolic link that points to it wherever you need.

Comment: Hello sir, I only need to upload the .zip file in the desktop of the server which is ubuntu OS. Instead using of this `$file->move(public_path().'/system/', $name, $extension);  ` What should be the right path for that folder in the server computer desktop? `$file->move('/folder in the desktop of server comuputer/', $name, $extension);  `

Comment: I meant that there's no such thing as a "computer desktop" by itself, so there really isn't a path for that. What you see in your desktop is the content of a folder called Desktop in a user's home.

Comment: Now, about Laravel, it is run by the web server service, which has its own user, and probably not the user you use to log in and see the desktop, in addition it should have permission to read only in the web projects root and write only in the public folder of avery project (and few others like the log folder but still in the project's root). So the question as it is does not make much sense, however you can find workarounds, like a symbolic link or scheduled tasks (cronjobs) that copy or moves regularly the files to a specified folder.

Comment: If the web server is run by the same user you use to login (which is absolutely NOT recommended), you can try to put the absolute path instead of public_path(), like $file->move('/home/youruser/Desktop/', name, $extension), I'm not sure that it would work, but I'm very sure you shouldn't do it like this.

Comment: Okay thanks sir @devtect... I will configure this out.

Comment: You're very welcome! Just, if the answer helped you out please accept it, or vote it up. This is important for both contributors and future readers.

Comment: I installed sftp and the adapter in my Laravel... to be able to upload file in the server in ubuntu.

Comment: Good thinking! That's a way too, didn't occur to me. Just take good care of the permissions.

Comment: Yeah, 757 is the good practice. In your suggestion what is the best to use. Filezilla or Anyplace Control. In my previous job I used APC in Filemaker development.

Comment: Well, the permissions depend on your real needs and they should be as strict as possible. So, I'm just wondering, why 757? That way you just block the write ability to the group members, while everyone else can do it.